# Sum of infinitely many really small numbers?

Tags: number-theory

$\sum_{x=1}^\infty \lim_{x\to0} x$, is this equal to zero or something peculiar as $-\frac{1}{12}$? This problem is not something i found in a textbook, my mind just makes up questions that i am not capable of answering. I would appreciate if someone put proper tags on this question. Sorry for my terrible english.

Note: Bad idea to do math late at night, what i sould have writen was as follows:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lim_{x\to0} x \cdot n$

Comment: Because of the reuse of $x$, your expression is meaningless.

Comment: The exression $$\int_0^x f(x)dx = f(0)dx + f(dx)dx + f(2dx)dx + \ ... \ + f(x)dx$$

is a sum of infinitely small numbers but it can be any number you want depending on the choice of function.

Comment: @saldukoo Sort of. If you really want to treat an integral as a genuine sum, and not a limit of sums, you need to work in something like [nonstandard analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_analysis), in which case the terms are *not* arbitrarily small - while infinitesimal, there are quantities infinitesimal relative to them again. In general, I think this is a bad option, and that the integral shouldn't be viewed as an actual sum, but opinions vary.

Comment: In an attempt to find a matrix-based method for the "summing-of-like-powers" in the sense of Faulhaber's and Bernoulli's formulae, I've assumed, that  subdiagonal entries in the Pascal-matrix ***P*** can formally be expressed as $1/\omega, 1/2/\omega, 1/3/\omega,...$ where $\omega = (-1)!$ and are thus zero in all finite computations, but "occur" as finite values when infinite series of powers of ***P*** are considered - giving the correct solution for the Faulhaber-polynomials.(... contd...)

Comment: (... contd...) It might be seen as "finding correct result by wrong method" but is possibly of interest. See http://go.helms-net.de/math/binomial_new/04_3_SummingOfLikePowers.pdf on page 14 ff, where the "ZETA"-matrix is considered.

Comment: @NoahSchweber My understanding is that, in NSA, an integral is defined as the _standard part_ (that is, the closest real number) of an infinite sum. (I mean, you could also write it directly as the infinite sum of infinitesimals, but that's true of any number.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}x$ is just a fancy name for $0$. And $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ (I presume you meant "$n$" as opposed to "$x$" - otherwise you're overloading variables, and the expression isn't meaningful) is just the limit as $m\rightarrow\infty$ of $\sum_{n=1}^m$.

Since $\sum_{n=1}^m0=0$ for all $m$, this means $\sum_{n=1}^\infty0=0$ - so your expression is just $0$.

Comment: In other words, I should go to bed and stop writing nonsense?